# Going to Another View Controller That Is Assigned Another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used the control, click a button, and drag the line to the target view controller method to link my two view controllers.

It worked fine but when I changed one of my view controller's classes, xCode goes to a page named main.m, minimizes my iOS Stimulator, and throws this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-   [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "33a-uy-08f-view-H7E-W0-NvO" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

How do I fix this?

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Game.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Game : UITableViewController

@end
```

Main.storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be its because you created a subclass of `UITableViewController` but you xib has no `UITableView`. If you make you class as a subclass of UIViewController which conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols and this will go away.

Hope this helps.. :)

**Edit:**

Here is the problem

```
@interface Game : UITableViewController
```

You see, Game is a subclass of `UITableViewController` but in your storybord there is no `UITableView`. A subclass of `UItableViewController` needs to have a `UITableView` in xib. Change the code to this:

```
@interface Game : UIViewController
```

Hope it'll solve your problem.